# Block with overflow:auto goes out of parent inline-block

Tags: html, css, popupwindow

http://jsfiddle.net/k88bqjnj/7/

I'm trying to make a popup window.
Css:

```
.c1{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
z-index: 1003;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 49px;
}
.c2{
    display: inline-block;
background: #e9e9e9;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
margin: auto;
padding: 20px;
max-height: 80%;
max-width: 90%;
}
.c3{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="c1">
    <div class="c2">
        <div>header</div>
        <div class="c3">
            *long text*
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The thing is c3 block goes out of c2 when I want it reach the bottom border of c2 and become scrollable.

I need c2 block size to depend on a browser window size and to keep header on top. The best solution yet is setting max-height to c3 block.

Comment: You should set some height for `.c3` div. eg. http://jsfiddle.net/bhavesh_gangani/k88bqjnj/1/

Comment: You could also apply overflow:auto to .c2 if you dont mind the header being scrolled away

Answer (score 2):

Add height in `[.c3][1]`

[**Update Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_j/k88bqjnj/5/)

```
.c3{
    overflow: auto;
    height:180px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add

```
overflow: scroll;
```

to c2's CSS

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t56ttoL9/)

Comment: I need to keep header on top

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your `overflow: auto` property to your `.c2` intead adding it to your siblings `.c3` [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k88bqjnj/6/)

```
.c2{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #e9e9e9;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 90%;
    overflow:auto;  -->> ADDED
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"overflow: auto" works if there is constraint (width or height).
In you case, you have applied a overflow on the content (.c3) and not the container (.c2).
Just by moving "overflow: auto" rules to the container (.c2) should make what you expect.

```
.c2{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #e9e9e9;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    max-height: 80%;
    max-width: 90%;

    overflow: auto; /* add me */
}
.c3{
    /* overflow: auto; delete me*/
}
```

Here is the result http://jsfiddle.net/vLrjqzcq/